# What can a service do on Windows?

Tags: services, malware, windows-services

What kind malware/spyware could someone put into a service that doesn't have it's own process on windows? I mean services that use svchost.exe for example, like this:
[image]

Could a service spy on my keyboard input? Take screenshots? Send/receive data over the internet? Infect other processes or files? Delete files? Kill processes?

Comment: **Anything its programmed to do.**  A service could do all the things you mention if its programmed to do so.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What is a service?

A service *is* an application, no more, no less.  The advantage is that a service can run without a user session.  This allows things like databases, backups, the ability to login, etc to run when needed and without a user logged in.

What is [svchost](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-svchostexe-and-why-is-it-running/)?

> According to Microsoft: “svchost.exe is a generic host process name for services that run from dynamic-link libraries”. Could we have that in english please?
>
> Some time ago, Microsoft started moving all of the functionality from internal Windows services into .dll files instead of .exe files. From a programming perspective this makes more sense for reusability… but the problem is that you can’t launch a .dll file directly from Windows, it has to be loaded up from a running executable (.exe). Thus the svchost.exe process was born.

So, essentially a service which uses svchost is just calling a .dll and can do pretty much ***anything*** with the right credentials and/or permissions.

If I remember correctly, there are viruses and other malware that do hide behind the svchost process, or name the executable svchost.exe to avoid detection.

Comment: To take it one step further, if you use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and you hover over the svchost instance it will tell you [what services it is hosting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QRfGh.png).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You can also just right click and `Go to Service(s)` in the built-in task manager on any recent version of Windows (Vista+).

Comment: The Windows 8 Taskmanager makes it even easier: http://250kb.de/u/140522/p/ZFP0uJMz2yVJ.png

Comment: @Forivin I'm curious how you managed to get a PNG to load in an *upwards* direction. And how you managed to get that to 1.5 MB - a PNG of mostly flat colours like that should be a couple hundred kB, max.

Comment: @Bob You're actually not the first one to ask me that. :p  
I'm too lazy to find out why, but I created this screenshot by using AltGr+Print (loads a bitmap screenshot of the current window in the clipboard) and then pasted into an empty png file using Paint, so it's likely that it still is a bitmap (with a wrong extension). That would explain the size and maybe also the upwards loading. ;)

Comment: If you really wanna know, open the file with a notepad and check the first 4 bytes, if they are not �PNG, then it's not a png.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to determine what processes are running under svchost is to use:

Tweaking.com - svchost.exe Lookup Tool V1.5.0

http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/tweaking_com_svchost_exe_lookup_tool.html

Works well.